# Return mongodb queries who have their due date + 12 hours?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongoose, database

I have events objects which have 2 params:
'at'  for when they start,
'due' for when they end

This is the structure of the array which is pretty straightforward:

```
{
   "name" : "war machine",
   "due" : ISODate("2015-11-09T15:30:00.000Z"),
   "at"  : ISODate("2015-11-09T11:30:00.000Z"),
}
```

I want to have a query, if possible, that will do this:

1) return the events which have their "at" time lower than Date.now.
   This one is easy enough:

```
this.model('Ev').find(
    {at:{$lt:Date.now()}
}).exec();
```

2) return the ones which have dueDate + 12 hours lower than now.
meaning if the event due is now, it will still return this object for me in the next 12 hours.

For example, if i do the first query only and than using javascript:

```
var dueTime = 43,200,000; // 12 hours in millseconds
  eventsReturned.forEach(function(e){

            if ( Date.now() - event.due.getTime() < dueTime ) {
               //This event should return
            }
        });
```

I have the result i want, How can i do so in the query with no javascript involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "Date.now() - event.due.getTime() < dueTime" returns the correct output it can be formulated as follows:

```
Date.now() - event.due.getTime() < dueTime
=>
Date.now() < dueTime + event.due.getTime()
=>
Date.now() - dueTime < event.due.getTime()
=>
event.due.getTime() > Date.now() - dueTime
```

and the last row is the same as

```
timeWindow = 12 * 60 * 60000
this.model('Ev').find(
    {due:{$gt:(Date.now() - timeWindow)}
}).exec();
```

Also as a side note since I'm not exactly sure what you expect it to return, it will return the event always when current time is less than "event.due.getTime() + 12hrs", i.e.,

```
at                due     due+12hrs
|------------------|---------|
                          <--
```

But, if you wish it to return events that are due but not yet "due+12hrs" then just add another query parameter:

```
timeWindow = 12 * 60 * 60000
this.model('Ev').find(
    {due:{$gt:(Date.now() - timeWindow)},
    {due:{$lt:Date.now()}}
}).exec();
```

Which would be:

```
at                due     due+12hrs
|------------------|---------|
                    -->   <--
```

Answer (score -2):

3*24*60*60000 = 3 days

so

12*60*60000 = 12 hrs

dueDate = date.Now() + (12*60*60000);

```
this.model('Ev').find(
    {at:{$lt:dueDate}
}).exec();
```

Personally I haven't tested the code. Do it and let me know if it works :)

Comment: NO, not now +12, i need the due date of the event! + 12...if it was that easy i wouldn't ask

Comment: why not add that + 12hr in the query itself.
this.model('Ev').find(
    {at:{$lt:dueDate +( < code to add+12hr here>)}
}).exec();

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem, in every object i have a due date, i need to show only those who have ( event.dueDate + 12 hours ) < Date.now...I need to extract and do something with a data inside of this object, the due data i mean